# Two's Complement as simple as possible without higher order functions

Tags: haskell, twos-complement

For a homework I am asked to implement the two's complement method in Haskell, which when given a list of numbers in Binary returns the two's complement list of that list.

```
>>>twoComplement [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]
[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
```

Therefore I am not allowed to use higher order functions, such as `last`, `init`, etc. This has to be as simple as possible. I want to learn to write beautiful code.

I would like to do this without the use of reverse functions, but I am allowed to, if necessary.

I already tried a lot of things. I understand that I need to flip all the bits, which is not to complicated.

```
flipBits [] = []
flipBits (x:xs)
         |x == 0 = 1:flipBits xs
         |x == 1 = 0:flipBits xs
         |otherwise: error "Only 0 and 1 are allowed."
```

But the adding one part feels really complicated to me. Especially with the carry over if I add a 1 to an already existing 1. Also list generators are not allowed. This is all about understanding lists and the concatenator `:`.

**Edit:** With the help of vkuo I wrote the following, which seems to be doing the job pretty well so far.

```
twoComplement:: [Integer] -> [Integer]
twoComplement [] = []
twoComplement lst = turn(tC(turn(lst)))
                where
                    tC (x:xs)
                        |x == 1 = 1:flipp xs
                        |x == 0 = x:tC xs
                    flipp [] = []
                    flipp(x:xs)
                        |x == 0 = 1:flipp xs
                        |x == 1 = 0:flipp xs
                    turn [] = []
                    turn (x:xs) = turn xs ++ [x]
```

If we want to use `reverse`, we have to make it ourselves. So I did that. Is there a way without reverse I wonder ?

Comment: Show what you've tried for your `twoComplement` function and others will be more likely to help you out. You can't expect others to just write up the code for you.

Comment: Anther way to think of twos complement is to scan your bit string right to left until hitting the first one, then invert all the bits following that one.

Comment: `last` and `init` are not [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)...

Comment: I'd change `twoComplement` to operate on `[Bool]` instead of (presumably) `[Int]` so that the type is tighter. Then you can rewrite `flipBits` without an error case.

Comment: "I want to learn to write beautiful code." that usually means you use **more**, not less, of library functions, especially including pre-built recursion schemes.

Comment: @Cactus good Idea. But the task says that we need to accept a list of Integers

Comment: @Swift I'd still push out the garbage to the periphery as far as possible, i.e. convert it from `[Integer]` to `[Bool]` as the first step, do everything in terms of `Bool`s, then convert back at the end.

Comment: @Cactus, one should arguably use `data Bit = Zero | One deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show)` rather than `Bool`.

Comment: @dfeuer: Absolutely.

Comment: Have you understood the problem description correctly? You say it specified accepting a list of integers, are you sure these integers are supposed to represent the bits that you operate on or should they be arbitrary integer values on which you each perform a twos compliment operation returning a list of twos complimented values. I'd suspect the latter since the former seems superfluous and ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont't want to reverse, then at any time you see an orignal digit and the result from the remainder of the list. The result from the remainder is a two's complement plus a carry digit. You have to return a result of the same type, i.e a carry digit plus a two's complement, albeit with one more digit taken into account.

Something like this:

```
invAdd :: Int -> (Int,[Int]) -> (Int,[Int])
invAdd 0 (0,ds) = (0,1:ds)
invAdd 0 (1,ds) = (1,0:ds)
invAdd 1 (0,ds) = (0,0:ds)
invAdd 1 (1,ds) = (0,1:ds)
```

Now if you had just one digit, then the whole operation would be:

```
twos :: [Int] -> (Int,[Int])
twos (d:[]) = invAdd d (1,[])
```

The `(1,[])` caters for the `1` you have to add in addtion to flipping the bits.

If you have more than one digit you need to recurse down

```
twos (d:ds) = invAdd d (twos ds)
```

This gives you the two's complement plus the final carry bit. If you don't want to see the carry, use `snd`:

```
*Main> snd (twos [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0])
[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
```

You can easily do this with Bools as well, because no math functions are used and in `invAdd` all cases are explicitly spelled out.